# Resizing a LVM partition

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xen

I'm running XCP-ng and I want to mount a partition in which I can store ISOs. I want it to be 30Gb out of the 2Tb storage that I have. Can someone help me with this? I've tried gparted but it doesn't let me resize the LVM volume. I'm hesitant on using fdisk cause that can potentially erase everything if I don't do things right.

Comment: LVM volumes can be resized with `lvresize`. You can also use `lvextend` to increase, and `lvreduce` to reduce the size. If there is a filesystem on that volume, use the `-r` option to resize it as well. Note, however, that XFS filesystems can only grow, not shrink. `fdisk` is unable to resize LVM volumes.

Comment: @berndbausch Okay so once I've subtracted the 30Gb out using `lvreduce`, can I format that into ext4? And how would I go about mounting it back so I can use it to save ISO images.

Comment: You mean you have 30Gb free space in the volume group? Create a 30GB volume, `mkfs -t ext4 NEWVOLUME` and mount it.